# Covariance between slope parameters/regression coefficients in a regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients, descriptive-statistics

Let's assume a three-variable regression model.

$$
\large
Y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2X_{2i} + \beta_3X_{3i} + u_i
$$

Can you derive the formula of covariance given below?

$$
\large
var(\hat{\beta_3}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\Sigma{x^2_{3i}(1-r^2_{23})}}
$$

$$
\large
se(\hat{\beta_3}) = +\sqrt{var(\hat{\beta_3)}}
$$

$$
\large
cov(\beta_2,\beta_3) = \frac{-r_{23}\sigma^2}{(1-r^2_{23})\sqrt{\Sigma{x^2_{2i}}}\sqrt{\Sigma{x^2_{3i}}}}
$$

I understand that with the help of the coefficient of determination's formula and the formula of variance given above, I can derive the formula. However, I can't understand where the negative sign came from in the numerator.